# Multiplicar prefixos de tabela

Tags: php

Existe alguma função em php para substituir `#_` por múltiplos prefixos de tabela exemplo `Test,test2,test3,test4`

```
->from ( '#__dolar_corrent AS a' )->leftJoin ( '#__users' )
```

Answer (score 3):

Tem esta:

```
str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )
```

Aplicando ao seu caso:

```
->from ( str_replace( '#_', 'Test', '#__dolar_corrent AS a' ) ) etc
```

Se quiser numerar num *loop* por exemplo:

```
$from = '#__dolar_corrent AS a';
$join = '#__users';
for($i = 1; $i < 5; ++$i) {
    ...
    $pref = 'Test'.$i;
    ->from(str_replace('#_', $pref, $from))->leftJoin(str_replace('#_', $pref, $join));
    ...
}
```

Vale lembrar que isso só faz sentido se você não puder alterar os prefixos. Com concatenação é muito mais simples:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 5; ++$i) {
    ...
    $from = 'Test'.$i.'_dolar_corrent AS a';
    $join = 'Test'.$i.'_users';
    ->from($from)->leftJoin($join);
    ...
}
```

Se quiser omitir o `1` deixando `Test, Test2, Test3` como na pergunta, em vez de:

```
'Test'.$i
```

use:

```
'Test'.($i>1?$i:'')
```

em qualquer um dos casos.

Comment: Obrigado por ter respondido. eu queria mesmo é com um juntar todos os 29 prefixo que tenho em um arquivo so. ->from ( '#__dolar_corrent AS a' )->leftJoin ( '#__users' ) o #_ e um prefixo

Comment: O código acima troca #_ por Teste1... como pedido na pergunta, fora do que foi perguntado, eu não tenho como responder, não teria como eu adivinhar o que não foi dito, né :)

Comment: Não entendo o que você chama de cópia da pergunta. Sua pergunta está no topo da página, pergunta como trocar #_ por multiplos prefixos. Dei exemplo de como trocar um, e de como trocar vários com base no que está na pergunta. Lá não fala nada de texto, nem quantos são, nem o critério. Respondi com base no que dava, mas seja lá como for, acredito que seja fácil adaptar para o seu caso real. Sugiro, em perguntas subsequentes dar mais detalhes, assim podemos ser mais precisos nas respostas também. Aqui tem umas dicas: [ask] e algo sobre o [ProblemaXY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499).